# Get formatted values from custom Form Request - Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5.6, php-7.2

I`m using custom form request to validate all input data to store users.

I need validate the input before send to form request, and get all validated data in my controller.

I have a regex function ready to validate this input, removing unwanted characters, spaces, allow only numbers and etc.

Would to get all data validated in controller, but still have no success.

```
Input example:
```

$cnpj= 29.258.602/0001-25

```
How i need in controller:
```

$cnpj= 29258602000125

```
UsuarioController

class UsuarioController extends BaseController
{
    public function cadastrarUsuarioExterno(UsuarioStoreFormRequest $request)
  {
     //Would to get all input validated - no spaces, no!@#$%^&*, etc 
     $validated = $request->validated();

     dd($data);
  }
...
}
```

---

```
UsuarioStoreFormRequest

<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsuarioStoreFormRequest extends FormRequest
{

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{

    return [
        'cnpj' => 'required|numeric|digits:14',
    ];
}
```

---

```
Custom function to validate cnpj

function validar_cnpj($cnpj)
{
$cnpj = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', (string) $cnpj);
// Valida tamanho
if (strlen($cnpj) != 14)
    return false;
// Valida primeiro dígito verificador
for ($i = 0, $j = 5, $soma = 0; $i < 12; $i++)
{
    $soma += $cnpj{$i} * $j;
    $j = ($j == 2) ? 9 : $j - 1;
}
$resto = $soma % 11;
if ($cnpj{12} != ($resto < 2 ? 0 : 11 - $resto))
    return false;
// Valida segundo dígito verificador
for ($i = 0, $j = 6, $soma = 0; $i < 13; $i++)
{
    $soma += $cnpj{$i} * $j;
    $j = ($j == 2) ? 9 : $j - 1;
}
$resto = $soma % 11;
return $cnpj{13} == ($resto < 2 ? 0 : 11 - $resto);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `prepareForValidation` method in your `FormRequest`. This way your input would be modified and replaced in the request before it is validated and you can normally retrieve it in the controller with `$request->get('cnpj');` after the validation was successful.

```
public function prepareForValidation()
{
    $input = $this->all();

    if ($this->has('cnpj')) {
        $input['cnpj'] = $this->get('cnpj'); // Modify input here
    }

    $this->replace($input);
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach if the goal is to update the field before validation.

Comment: Thanks @remul

I used the above function and managed to solve the problem, the data is validated and returned to the controller

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the validated function in `UsuarioStoreFormRequest` as follows

```
/**
 * Get the validated data from the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function validated()
{
    $validated = parent::validated();

    //Add here more characters to remove or use a regex
    $validated['cnpj'] = str_replace(['-', '/', ' ', '.'], '', $validated['cnpj']);

    return $validated;
}
```

Comment: I added this function in my request form, and still could not retrieve the validated data in my controller.
I apologize because I do not have so much experience with development.

Comment: Can you add a ```dd('test')``` inside the validated function above to make sure it is called from your controller? It should be added to ```UsuarioStoreFormRequest``` class

Comment: Add the function validated()  in UserStoreFormRequest, but when I send the data via postman I have the following result:
     "message": "The given data was invalid.", .....
Which makes sense, since the validation is in operation, so its function is not being performed before validation.
Could you please send some examples so that I can compare and understand better,  thanks for the support.

Comment: That function will be called when you run ```$validated = $request->validated();```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$string = "29.258.602/0001-25";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);
return (implode("",$matches[0]));
```

Hope its help

Comment: Hi @ shariff854, sorry but where do I add this code? In function rules before validate?

Comment: If you test this code. you always get just numbers from string. I dont know what you want to do . but I think you first should use this code before validate.check it and let me know about it